# Issue with install iverilog and gtkwave on CentOS 8

Tags: centos

I'm trying to install iverilog and gtkwave on our CentOS 8 however it always prompted about
Problem: conflicting requests

- nothing provides libtcl8.5.so()(64bit) needed by gtkwave-3.3.61-1.el7.x86_64
- nothing provides libtk8.5.so()(64bit) needed by gtkwave-3.3.61-1.el7.x86_64

Any idea how to get this resolved?
I'm referring to attached commands but not sure how to download as mentioned in their step 1?

Any advice would be much appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`.el7.` tells us the package you're trying to install is for CentOS 7, not 8.

This won't work. You need to install a version of gtkwave that is built against the library versions in *your* version of CentOS, not the previous one.

Since gtkwave has an [EPEL8 branch](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/gtkwave) I'm not sure how you even came to install the EPEL7 package. Possibly you've somehow enabled the wrong EPEL release? but that's hard, seeing that `dnf install epel-release` would give you the right one.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I followed your advice, it showed me the downloading progress bar but it ended with GPG check FAILED, do I need to install the public key manually?

Comment: /var/cache/dnf/download-ib01.fedoraproject.org_pub_epel_7_x86_64_-6e39d5080d92538d/packages/adobe-source-code-pro-fonts-2.030.1.050-5.el7.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 352c64e5: NOKEY
Public key for adobe-source-code-pro-fonts-2.030.1.050-5.el7.noarch.rpm is not installed
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED

Comment: Hi Marcus, I would like to update you that it's solved by using another epel repo, it was the wrong epel_7 being used in the first place. All good after I disabled it and add the one for epel_8

Comment: that's exactly what I said in my answer, so that makes me happy!